# The file temp.pdf could not be opened ¿Cómo obtener el texto de un pdf con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Intento obtener el texto de un pdf con Python (uno de mi CV, pdf):

```
def extract_text_from_pdf_binary(pdf_binary):
    doc = fitz.open(stream=pdf_binary, filetype="pdf")
    num_pages = doc.page_count

    text = ''
    for page_number in range(num_pages):
        page = doc.load_page(page_number)
        text += page.get_text()

    doc.close()
    return text

binary = file.read()
print(binary[0:300])
text = extract_text_from_pdf_binary(binary)
print("text: ", text)
```

Sin embargo obtengo:

```
b"\nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<< /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 10987 >>\nstream\nx\xda\xdd\x9d]s#U\x9an\xef\xf9\x15u31r\x04\x95\x93\xfb+?\xfa\x0e(\xe8\xa0\x07\x18\xa0\x98\xe9\x131=\x17*;\xb1\xd5\xd8r\xb5%\x17\xd4\xfc\xfa\xf3\xec\xfd\xa4\\\xe5\x02b\xbaYE\xc49\x13DP\xb6>\x96\x94\x99+\x95\x92^Y\xab\x7f\xd2\xeb\xbf\xbb\xcb\xf6O\xff\xe4\xdb?~\xd0?\xa9\xbf\xd4\x7f\x7fvN\x17\xe3\x93\xbe\xcbE\xff\x1b\xdb9\x8fN\xd0%>\xfe\xee\x83\x7f\xf9,\xceOB\xeeR\x1e\xe2\x93\xef\xbe\x7f2\x95.\x96\xf1\xc9\x98\x87n\xcc:\xe5\xe2\xc9\x7fn\xbe\xbe\x7fq\xbd;\xdf\x1ew\xb7\xfb\xc3\xd9\x7f}\xf7\xa7\xdft[\x9f~\xf7\xc1\xdf>\x08\xed\xf2\xe1\xcd\xad\xc4n\x1a\x87'\xe77\x1f\xfc\xe7\x7f\xf5O.t\xde\x9ft\xf94OO~l\x97\xbc\xd1o\xf3<\xe8\xa7\xeb'\xcf?\xf8\xe6m\xc2 BB\x84\xb1\x8byF\x84I\x84\x82\x08\xb3\x08\x91\x10f"
text:
```

Entonces parece que hay cosas en `file` pero `extract_text_from_pdf_binary` no es capaz obtenerlo. Intente varios otros possibilidades como:

```
def extract_summary(file):
    if file.filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".pdf", delete=False) as temp_file:
            temp_filename = temp_file.name
            file.save(temp_filename)

            pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(temp_filename)
            num_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)

            extracted_text = ''
            for page_layout in extract_pages(temp_filename):
                for element in page_layout:
                    if isinstance(element, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
                        obj_str = element.get_text()
                        extracted_text += obj_str

            summary = get_summary(extracted_text)

            # Supprimez le fichier temporaire après utilisation
            os.remove(temp_filename)

            return summary
```

Pero no puedo leer el archivo. Obtengo: `The file temp.pdf could not be opened`

Aqui esta un screenshot del pdf:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algunas cosas a revisar: Estás seguro que la página tiene un texto? no será una imagen? El pdf tiene contraseña? tiene habilitado el permiso para copiar y pegar?

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho Si, la pagina tiene un texto y no tiene contrasena. Anadi un screenshot de la pagina.